# Derivative of a reciprocal function

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

If I want to prove that a partial derivative $\frac{\partial D}{\partial x}$ is either positive or negative, and $D=\frac{1}{E}$, then how can I use the partial derivative $\frac{\partial E}{\partial x}$ (which is a simplier derivative) to prove this?

Comment: Note that as $E$ increases, $D$ decreases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\;\cfrac{\partial D}{\partial x}=\cfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\cfrac{1}{E}\right)=-\cfrac{1}{E^2} \cfrac{\partial E}{\partial x}\;,\;$ then

$\;\cfrac{\partial D}{\partial x}>0\;\iff\;\cfrac{\partial E}{\partial x}<0\;,$

$\;\cfrac{\partial D}{\partial x}<0\;\iff\;\cfrac{\partial E}{\partial x}>0\;.$

So, if you want to prove that $\;\cfrac{\partial D}{\partial x}\;$ is positive, it is sufficient to prove that $\;\cfrac{\partial E}{\partial x}\;$ is negative, and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that is possible because continuity of the function itself might change.
For example
If your function is $xy$, then upon taking the reciprocal, $1/xy$ isn't continuous at $x=0$ and $y=0$. So ideally being able to reciprocate to differentiate will not give you an answer.

Also, let us assume the domain isn't an issue for us. Still, assume a function y=x which is a straight line with a positive slope. If you rewrite it as $y=1/x$, it is a  rectangular hyperbola that has a negative slope. So, this as per my knowledge doesn't seem possible

Comment: Actually, it is possible to use $\;\cfrac{\partial E}{\partial x}\;$ in order to prove that $\;\cfrac{\partial D}{\partial x}\;$ is either positive or negative.

Comment: I am a little confused here. Isn't there a possibility E won't exist in your domain and 1/E will be undefined?

Comment: Of course it is possible that $E$ does not exist or $E=0$ in some points, but we are considerating the function $D$ in its domain in which not only $E$ exist but also $E\ne0$.